# How to get time in seconds since process started, without using etimes?

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to use ps to find the number of seconds since a process started. The version of ps I have doesn't support etimes and not sure how else to get this info?

Comment: What is the operating system version?

Comment: It's on redhat 6.6

Comment: Then you need to check the /proc filesystem as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For process of pid 1234, you could use the *mtime* field of meta-data of pseudo-file `/proc/1234/status`. Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more. 
See also [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) and [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html).

So `date +%s` is giving the current date since the [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), e.g. 1479125355 now in November 14<sup>th</sup>, 2016. `stat -c %Y /proc/1234/status` is giving the start time of process 1234 since Unix epoch. You want the difference. Perhaps use (barely tested, my interactive shell is [zsh](http://zsh.org/)) 
 `$[$(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /proc/1234/status)]`; adapt that to your shell.

For example:

```
 bash -c 'sleep 4; echo $(($(date +%s) - $(stat -c %Y /proc/$$/status)))'
```

is giving me 4 as expected. Of course the `$$` is expanded to the pid of the `bash -c` command

Comment: For me the correct file to check was not /proc/$$/status, but /proc/$$/stat. (I'm on Linux 6.7.5)